# How to build a Metro app to custom folder

Tags: windows, msbuild, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to build my Blank App(XAML) for Windows store in custom folder via MSBuild.

In documentation is written that I should add the following attribute to my build command: /p:OutputPath="path", but MSBuild ignoring it. Also I've tried to add this property in .vcxproj but it gives no result.

My command in VS dev command prompt looks like this:

```
MSbuild "PathToApp\MySolution.sln" /p:Platform=Win32;OutputPath="MyPath"
```

How can I change output directory for my Metro app?

Comment: Hard to see the point, a WinRT app needs to be deployed before it can be tested.  The "real" output directory is in the Packages subdir.  There is no OutputPath property in C++ projects, the $(OutDir) macro matters.

Comment: I want to deploy multiple versions of the same application, for this I need to build it in multiple folders.

Comment: You can only ever have one version of a Modern UI app installed for a given user.